# Why is this program printing the reverse of the expected result?

Tags: c++, function, cin, erase

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     string in_code;
     std::cin >> in_code;
     int word;
     word = in_code.find(" ");
     in_code.erase(0, (word + 1));
     cout << in_code << endl;
}
```

This program should return "is_a_good_boy" when I give input "Jhon is_a_good_boy". But it prints "Jhon". Help me solve this, please.

Comment: That's because `>>` does not do what you think it does. Hint: use a debugger to examine its contents, before the `erase()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should approach this with getline in order to capture the whole line entered as well as do validation when using string.find

Commented example below.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string in_code; //String to store user input
    std::getline(std::cin, in_code); //Get user input and store in in_code

    int word = in_code.find(" "); //Get position of space (if one exists) - if no space exists, word will be set to std::string::npos
    if (word != std::string::npos) //If space exists
    {
        in_code.erase(0, word + 1); //erase text before & including space
        std::cout << in_code << std::endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The entered input did not contain a space." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```